# Conditionally display element in table

Tags: apex, visualforce

Problem: When utilizing a pageBlockTable to create a calendar, I am unable to conditionally display components in certain locations.

Right now I'm using this set up to populate my calendar:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!calendar}" var="a" rules="all" cellpadding="75%">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">SUNDAY<br/>(Morning)</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!a.Sunday[0].viewDate}"></apex:outputText>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Sunday[0].isChecked}"></apex:inputCheckbox>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header"><br/>(Afternoon)</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!a.Sunday[1].viewDate}"></apex:outputText>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Sunday[1].isChecked}"></apex:inputCheckbox>
                </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

This works well, however it will place checkboxes in every single square, even those without actual dates. Example:

[image]

When I attempt to use a flag from the controller and use an apex:variable element paired with render=flag to say whether or not a box should appear, it will remove the checkbox for the entire column rather than just for one row. Like this:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!calendar}" var="a" rules="all" cellpadding="75%">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">SUNDAY<br/>(Morning)</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!a.Sunday[0].viewDate}"></apex:outputText>
                    <apex:variable value="{!foo}" var="bar" rendered="{!a.Sunday[0].displayBox}" >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Sunday[0].isChecked}"></apex:inputCheckbox>
                    <apex:variable>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header"><br/>(Afternoon)</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!a.Sunday[1].viewDate}"></apex:outputText>
                    <apex:variable value="{!foo}" var="bar" rendered="{!a.Sunday[1].displayBox}" >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Sunday[1].isChecked}"></apex:inputCheckbox>
                    </apex:variable>
                </apex:column>
<apex:pageBlockTable>
```

[image]

How else can I approach this problem? Thanks

Comment: You can try `rendered` attribute of the checkbox itself like `<apex:inputCheckbox rendered="{!Expression}"`.

Comment: What does the code look like which isn't working correctly? Can you edit your question and add that detail? (boolean in the controller and apex:variable element in the table, etc.) Without that detail it is hard to know how to correct the issue.

Comment: I've edited the question, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also, thanks @SarojBera! Your answer is correct, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you need the `<apex:variable` tag in your use case and you should be able to put the rendered boolean directly on the `inputCheckbox`.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!calendar}" var="a" rules="all" cellpadding="75%">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">SUNDAY<br/>(Morning)</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!a.Sunday[0].viewDate}"></apex:outputText>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Sunday[0].isChecked}" rendered="{!a.Sunday[0].displayBox}"></apex:inputCheckbox>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column>
                    <apex:facet name="header"><br/>(Afternoon)</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!a.Sunday[1].viewDate}"></apex:outputText>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Sunday[1].isChecked}" rendered="{!a.Sunday[1].displayBox}"></apex:inputCheckbox>
                </apex:column>
<apex:pageBlockTable>
```

If that markup causes strange layout issues because of a missing element, you might consider wrapping the checkbox in a `<span>` by using a span tag or an `<apex:outputPanel>` so that when the checkbox isn't rendered, there is still a sibling element next to the text with the day number.

```
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">SUNDAY<br/>(Morning)</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!a.Sunday[0].viewDate}"></apex:outputText>
    <apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Sunday[0].isChecked}" rendered="{!a.Sunday[0].displayBox}"></apex:inputCheckbox>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:column>
```